# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'fill' of undefined

Tags: angular, svg

I want to do svg element attribute binding . My code as follows.
This is my HTML code:

```
   <g transform="translate(0,0)"  [routerLink]="['./malfunctionAdd']" class="pointer_curser">
                <rect x="50" y="10" width="100" height="50" rx="10" ry="10" stroke-width="2" stroke="black"  [attr.fill]="flowChartDatas[0].fill"></rect>
                <text x="100" y="40" font-size="14" fill="black" text-anchor="middle">{{flowChartDatas[0].name}}</text>
                <rect x="120" y="10" width="30" height="15" rx="0" ry="0" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" fill="red"></rect>
                <text x="135" y="23" font-size="12" fill="black" text-anchor="middle">0</text>
   </g>
```

Service code as follows.

```
getFlowChart(status?) {
    (!status) && (status = '1');
    let token = this.storageService.getToken('token');
    return this.http.post(
        `${environment.url.management}/workflow`,
        {
            "access_token": token,
            "type": "trouble_workflow_get",
            "data":{
                "status": status
            }
        }
    ).map((res: Response) => {
        let body = res.json();
        if( body.errcode !== '00000') {
            return [];
        }
        return body['datas'];
    })
}
```

Ts code as follows:

```
export class MalfunctionBaseComponent implements OnInit {
flowChartDatas = [];                    

constructor(private maintenanceService: MaintenanceService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.maintenanceService.getFlowChart().subscribe(res => {
        this.flowChartDatas = res;
    })
}
```

}

Everything seems fine and t**he data bingding is work for me**.But the console error when i open the F12, the error as follows.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'fill' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (MalfunctionBaseComponent.html:11)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14727)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13841)
at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14119)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13842)
at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14145)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13837)
at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
```

Anybody can help me? How to solve that problem, i am confuzed.
**Pay attention:

I use [attr.fill]="flowChartDatas[0].fill" instead of fill="{{flowChartDatas[0].fill}}". It is works for me . However the console still shows error
whatever I use prefix or not. [attr.fill]="flowChartDatas[0].fill" is work for me . but still console Cannot read property 'fill' of undefined. That is wired.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens because Angular thinks `rect` is an HTML tag. And fill isn't an HTML tag attribute !

try this instead :

```
<svg:rect ...>
```

Comment: I use [attr.fill]="flowChartDatas[0].fill" instead of fill="{{flowChartDatas[0].fill}}". It is works for me . However the console still shows error. how to solve this problem?

Comment: whatever I use prefix or not. [attr.fill]="flowChartDatas[0].fill" is work for me . but still console Cannot read property 'fill' of undefined. That is wired.

Comment: Ok then, if you don't believe me, then maybe [the same answer on a blog will convince you](http://teropa.info/blog/2016/12/12/graphics-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: i have used <svg: rect ..> , however the console still shows this error even it is work for me . I have saw this article.

Comment: Ooooooooooooooh wait. I've found your issue : `lowChartDatas[0]` is undefined. Is it a result of an HTTP call ?

Comment: sorry, i will edit my question again. Wait for me a while ,please.

Comment: yes ,it is resulf of an HTTP request and i am sure lowChartDatas[0] is not undefined because the value data bingding  was sucessful. I can check this after the page was loaded.

Comment: Can. Wait for me a while . Thanks.

Comment: It is undefined when you arrive on the page, and it has a value once your HTTP call is made.

Comment: Either you use a `*ngIf="lowChartDatas && lowChartDatas.length"`, or you use a getter `get fillColor() { return this.lowChartDatas && this.lowChartDatas.length ? this.lowChartDatas[0].fill : 'transparent'; }` (and you give the getter to the rect with `[attr.fill]="fillColor"`)

Comment: Well see ? Your `lowChartDatas` is an empty array at first

Comment: Can, i will try it and tell u whether works for me or not. ☺

Comment: Wooooooo! It is work for me ! U have my gratitude! ☺